# How to align font-icon exactly at the middle in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `select2` component in which I've added caret section at the end[image: marked in green] .

Here is the code that I've added

```
_caretSection = '<div class="select2-selection__arrawicon"><span><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span></div>'
var mainspancontrol = this.domElement.find(".select2-selection__rendered");
mainspancontrol.css("width", 'calc(100% - 25px)');
this.domElement.find(".select2-selection--multiple").append(_caretSection);
```

Below is the CSS that I've added.

```
.select2-selection__arrawicon {
    background-image: -khtml-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#F2F0F0), to(#C9C9C9));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F2F0F0, #C9C9C9);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F2F0F0, #C9C9C9);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #F2F0F0), color-stop(100%, #C9C9C9));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F2F0F0, #C9C9C9);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F2F0F0, #C9C9C9);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#F2F0F0, #C9C9C9);
    width: 25px;
    color: #000000;
    height: calc(100% - 2px);
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    display: grid;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 1px;
    right: 1px;
}
```

parent's css looks like below

```
.select2-container{

border-color: #e5e5e5 !important;
border-radius: 0px !important;
min-height: 25px !important;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
-webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
-o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
```

}
I believe there is no major styles related to positioning in the parent's css. Default select2's css will be applied to the parent.

But it looks distorted in the IE10. How could I achieve this in IE 10 and above??
[image]

Comment: We need to see the caret's parent/surrounding code, too. Can you give us just the html and css that recreates what you have in your screenshot?

Comment: Try `.select2-selection__arrawicon > span {vertical-align: middle}`

Comment: @MichaelCoker thanks for the quick response. I've updated the same in the question.

Comment: We need the parent/sibling HTML, too. Please give us just html and css that recreates your screenshot.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia no bro it dint worked.

Answer (score 1):

This is css from another example. Need add top and bottom = 0.

```
.select2-selection__arrow {
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 1px;
    width: 20px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

for arrow add top 50%. This is align arrow to vertical

```
.select2-selection__arrow > span {
    border-color: #888 transparent transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 4px 0 4px;
    height: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -4px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 0px;
}
```